# Magnetic force on different parts of a current loop causing torque

Tags: electromagnetism

[image: loo]

In this picture ,  $L_3$ is at a further distance and opposite orientation to $L_1$  from the current source. Hence there should be an imbalanced force and hence a torque but there is no rotation, why?

From: B = $\frac{u_o I}{2\pi r}$

and,$ F= I ( \vec{L} x\vec{B})$

Comment: Torque about which point/axis?

Comment: axis passing through center of square loop and perpendicualr to surface

Answer (score 0):

If you take the axis to be the axis perpendicular to the plane of the loop. $\vec{\tau}=\vec{r}\times\vec{F}$. $\vec{r}$ for both the force at $L_1$ and $L_3$ is parallel to the plane pointing from the respective centres towards the centre. Now assuming the Force acting on the arms of the loops ($L_1$ and $L_3$) is at the centre, due to the symmetry of the the loop, $\vec{r}$  is parallel and anti-parallel to the $\vec{F}$ for both arms respectively. This means that the torque is zero.

However you can get around the assumption, by saying that the force is acting at every point on the side $L_1$ and $L_3$. But if you do the calculation, then also you will get zero net torque. I am confident in this statement because of the symmetry of the loop. The amount of torque caused by half of the arm (say $L_3$) will be equal to the other half but in opposite direction. Similarly for $L_1$.